Consulta acerca de PDF Conjurer
estoy haciendo un trabajo en bubble.io con PDF Conjurer. En el workflow de un botón coloco que exporte el contenido de un repeating group a una table en el PDF. Quisiera saber si es posible colocarle una condición a una sola columna de la table. (La columna tiene la cuota actual y las cuotas totales, por ejemplo "1 de 2". Quiero saber si es posible hacer que si el número de cuotas totales es 1 entonces la celda diga "Unico Pago")

¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Donde está el Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask]
